# Reset mysql root password, now Node / Sequelize fails to load

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I done messed something up.

I am working on a Node / Express app that is using the Sequelize ORM to write to a local mysql DB for development. I loaded it up this morning, and it was fine. At some point in working today, I attempted to reset my mysql root password (for unrelated reasons). I did so, then attempted to restart the node server for my app, and it now fails to load. When running

```
node app.js
```

I get

```
TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
  at TypeError (<anonymous>)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:74:15)
  at module.exports.finish (/Users/DrHall/Desktop/gitRepos/CRPinit/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:142:30)
  at exec (/Users/DrHall/Desktop/gitRepos/CRPinit/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:96:16)
  at onError (/Users/DrHall/Desktop/gitRepos/CRPinit/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:72:11)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at null.<anonymous> (/Users/DrHall/Desktop/gitRepos/CRPinit/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dao-factory.js:299:42)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at null.<anonymous> (/Users/DrHall/Desktop/gitRepos/CRPinit/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:224:17)
  at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

I have found other people reporting this error message, but its vague enough that it has been for different reasons that the spesific failures I am getting. I am too new at this whole process to know what I did in the process of reset my root password that is not making Sequelize fail to load.

Mysql root loads fine with the new password. The app does not use the root user, it uses a separate user, who can also log in fine.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

---

Extra info to address questions asked:

TO reset the password I did use '-skip-grant-tables'. Running grep i saw that mysql was still running with that command, so I killed it and started it up again. Running ps -Af | grep mysql I get

```
501  7563     1   0  4:31PM ttys000    0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.14/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Lil-Coder.pid
501  7662  7563   0  4:31PM ttys000    0:00.44 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.14/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.14 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.14/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/Lil-Coder.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Lil-Coder.pid
501  7677  7460   0  4:32PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql
```

Which seems right? But the same error on trying to boot node.

---

I'm just going to file this one under 'W' for WTF. In the end what fixed it was basically nothing. I was connecting to the MySQL DB via Sequelize via:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: 3306
}),
```

with config being an external file I was requiring. I replaced all of the config. variables with the actual strings from the config file (copy/paste) and it worked. Copied them back, and it still worked. It's all voodoo to me.

Comment: "I attempted to reset my mysql root password" How did you do that exactly ? I suppose you started mysql with "skip-grant-tables", did you restart mysql afterwards ? Maybe mysql is still running with skip-grant-tables and that's the problem...

Comment: It looks like it was running with skip-grant-tables, but it I am still not getting it to work. Edited OP with more info.

Comment: Can you try running the database queries manually and see if they work ?

Comment: Yes - logging into mysql from the terminal command line, and running queries from there seems to work just fine. I can create/drop databases, tables and make inserts. I also tried a brew uninstall mysql, then a reinstall, and no luck.